# XML value from URL to text using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xml, matomo

I am trying to get a value from this URL (returns pure XML):

http://demo.piwik.org/?module=API&method=VisitsSummary.getUniqueVisitors&idSite=7&period=day&date=today&format=xml&token_auth=anonymous

And I want to store this value in this element on a separate site:

```
<div id="result" style="color:red"></div>
```

Every javascript or jquery attempt I try results in some "access-control-origin" error, which I understand to a point but I can't do anything about the remote server. I need a quick front-end solution.

Note: There is another format I can return the data in - JSON. But I have had similar issues above in trying to get that data as well.

Comment: use CORS: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: @Saar `I can't do anything about the remote server`

Comment: If the remote server doesn’t want to work with you on this (by enabling CORS) – then there _is_ no front-end solution.

Comment: In fact, server allows jsonp request, see e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/xLawn3hb/  so use it instead of XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are trying to make cross domain request and because server only allow jsonp for cross domain request, then use jsonp. For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://demo.piwik.org/?module=API&method=VisitsSummary.getUniqueVisitors&idSite=7&period=day&date=today&format=json&token_auth=anonymous',
    dataType: 'jsonp'
}).done(function(data){
    $('#result').html(data.value);
});
```

### -jsFiddle-